# Got 16.000 mp3 files in one folder. How can I put them into folders using a filter?

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, cmd

Got a bunch of mp3 files in one folder and i want them each artist to have their own folder.
I have tried doind manually, but i've only been able to complete about 5000 before giving up.

what i want is a command or script that would let me filter by a string on the filename and then move that into a folder.

thank you!

PS: using WIN7

Comment: Are your files in a strict format - such as `artist name - title` ?

Comment: Yes, Black Sabbath - When Death Calls.mp3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This processes all MP3 files in the folder that have `" - "` in the filename.

It will move a file called `"Angels - One Child.mp3"` into a folder called
`Angels` and rename the MP3 file to `One Child.mp3`

**Note 1:** A filename like `AC - DC - Rock Me.mp3` will only partially work
 because the folder will become `AC` and the file will be called `DC - Rock Me.mp3`

**Note 2:** A filename that contains `^` or `%` may not be handled correctly.

It requires you to launch the batch file like this: `moveMP3.bat !`
with the `!` as the first argument, so that it isn't run accidentally in another folder.

```
@echo off
if not %1.==!. echo Moves filenames aaa - bbb.*.mp3 to a folder named aaa and filename bbb.* - Syntax: "%~0" ! & pause & goto :EOF
:: Moves filenames aaa - bbb.* to a folder named aaa
setlocal
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir "* - *.mp3" /a:-d /b') do call :go "%%a"
pause
goto :EOF
:go
set "name=%~n1"
set "num=0"
set "found="
:loop
set /a num=num+1
call set "name2=%%name:~%num%,3%%"
if "%name2%"==" - " set /a found=%num%
if not defined found goto :loop
:: name2 is the aaa part
call set "name2=%%name:~0,%num%%%"
:: name1 is the bbb part
set /a num1=num+3
call set "name1=%%name:~%num1%%%"
md "%name2%" 2>nul
echo moving "%~1"
   move "%~1" "%name2%\" >nul
   ren "%name2%\%~1" "%name1%%~x1"
goto :EOF
```

This will move all mp3s with `peter` in the filename to a folder named `peter`

```
@echo off
set "string=peter"
for %%a in ("*%string%*.mp3") do (
md "%string%" 2>nul
move "%%a" "%string%" >nul
)
pause
```

Comment: Oh my God! that script was perfect! i re-read my questions and it wasn't 16000 MP3 files, it was 60.000.

I used the first script you gave me and organizing 20.000 files took me like 4 hours, so i was ready to give up again.... but with the new script is organizing them as i type!

Thank you so much @foxidrive ! I ♥ you!